# Responsive alignment of youtube iframes?

Tags: html, css

I want to show 3 youtube iframes and 1 paragraph in 4 divs.
On desktop view, I want them on 2X2
On responsive, I want them all on one line vertically aligned.

This is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">

.wrap_video {text-align: center; margin: 15px auto;}
.resp_video {display: inline-block; text-align: left; width: 33%; margin: 5% 5% 5% 5%;}
.resp_video.fixed {width: 100px; margin-right: 10px;}

</style>

<div class="wrap_video">
    <div id="a" class="resp_video"><iframe width="350" height="197" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ocQHSUALsOA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <div id="b" class="resp_video"><iframe width="350" height="197" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/P62o8O5KV6w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <div id="c" class="resp_video"><iframe width="350" height="197" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GSKcBNEPcfU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <div id="d" class="resp_video"> My paragraph<br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
```

When I check responsive view, the videos are still on one horizontal line instead of being one under the other one.

Someone ha san idea please how to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `min-width` on the `resp_video` class. Then when they reach that size, they will not shrink any further, thus sending the next inline-block to the next line. http://jsbin.com/fagujoyiqi/edit?html,output